# pivot table: "Summarize Values By" -> Sum in Excel 2016 - keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, pivot-table

When you create a pivot table, Excel often defaults to counting numeric values instead of using "Sum". I often have to change it manually via "Summarize Values By" -> Sum. In Excel 2010 I used to be able to add this option to the Quick Access Toolbar and invoke it through a keyboard shortcut like ALT+2:

[image: Add to quick access toolbar]

In Excel 2016 the option is no longer in the ribbon. Is there any way I can assign a keyboard shortcut to invoke this option?

Comment: Are you talking about the field settings?

Comment: @Raystafarian: yup.